# How do you replace getty to point to a custom login screen

Tags: linux, console

Is it possible to replace/redirect/override the getty() implementation to point to a custom screen instead of its default behavior. The idea here is to ensure authentication happens from this(custom) screen.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's wrong with just using your... "custom screen"?

Comment: 1. How do you implement that "custom screen" that is the primary question :) ?

Comment: Have you examined *getty's source code yet?

Comment: No, Is there a "safer" way to override or redirect and use a custom implementation by say changing a configuration file somewhere?